How to update a preact signal value in a react typescript project?
I am trying out signals from @preact/signals in a ReactTS project. According to the documentation, if I would like to update a signal value, I can just do mySignal.value = "newSignal".
However, this throws a typescript error: "Cannot assign to 'value' because it is a read-only property. ts(2540)"
Code:
import { signals } from "@preact/signals";

const name = signal<string>("John Oliver");

console.log(name.value); // "John Oliver"

name.value = "Jon Stewart" // throws typescript error: cannot assign to read-only property


Question:
So how can I update a preact signal in a typescript project?
System info
{
    ...
    "dependencies": {
        ...
        "@preact/signals": "^1.2.3",
        "react": "^18.3.1",
        "typescript": "^4.9.5",
        ...
    }
}


I'm not able to reproduce. The error would make sense if you were trying to assign to a computed signal, since those are read only.

If you're using React you should be using @preact/signals-react, not @preact/signals. That's the Preact integration.

# Just the core library
npm install @preact/signals-core
# If you're using Preact
npm install @preact/signals
# If you're using React
npm install @preact/signals-react
# If you're using Svelte
npm install @preact/signals-core

https://github.com/preactjs/signals?tab=readme-ov-file#installation

